# Microsoft.Office.Interop.outlook doesn't work

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, outlook

I am developing a small project where I need to be able to retrieve emails from an Outlook mailbox in order to process the emails received.

I took an old program made in VB.net to rewrite it in C #.
With the project in Vb.net I have no errors

However I have this error: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException : 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The specified file can not be found.'` with the C# project.

My references :

[image]
[image]

When I compare the Microsoft.Office.Interop.outlook library to the project in Vb.net installed is exactly the same (same version, etc.).

So if you have an idea to solve this problem I am interested :D

Comment: Are you working with M365 mailboxes? If so [use the MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) instead of interop. There are very few reasons to use interop with Office in 2020.

Comment: I'm working with Office 16

Comment: You are working with Office 16 but trying to use office 15 dll ?

Comment: But i add the Microsoft office interop Outlook 16 (I added a screenshoot to my post) so i suppose is the good version for Office 16 or i do a mistake ?

Comment: You can refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399420/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-office-version-15-0-0-0). In addition, you can try to add <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes> to your csproj file. Please also refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5735).

Comment: @LauraDestier, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following steps to solve the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` problem.

First, you need to change the current framework to .NET Core 3.0.

[image]

Second, Select Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, right click properties and set "Embed Interop Types" to "Yes".

[image]

Finally, you can use the following code to retrieve emails from an Outlook mailbox.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


            Outlook.Application oApp = null;
            oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.Items items = null;
            try
            {
                // use default profile and DO NOT pop up a window
                // on some pc bill gates fails to login without the popup, then we must pop up and lets use choose profile and allow access
                nameSpace.Logon("", "", false, Missing.Value);
                var folder = nameSpace.Folders["emailaddress"].Folders["Folder"];
                items = folder.Items;
                foreach (Outlook.MailItem item in items)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // use default profile and DO pop up a window
                nameSpace.Logon("", "", true, true);
            }
```